# Problems creating a new Document-based Core Data project

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, core-data

I am trying to create a Core Data-based Mac OS X application. I've used Core Data on iOS, but things are a little different with AppKit. I am also using Xcode 4.1 on 10.7, and I know some Core Data things have changed on Lion. The only up-to-date reference from Apple is a recent WWDC session, which promises/suggests updated references on Apple.com, but most of the Core Data stuff is very out of date.

To start, I used Xcode to generate a Document-based project using Core Data. I hollowed out some of the Main Menu bits (deleted some menu items) and got rid of the `NSWindow` object inside `Main Menu.xib`, creating my own `MyDocument.xib` with a `NSWindow` (and sub-views) instead.

Questions:

1. I assume that a Persistent Store Controller always needs a persistent store, so if a new document is created, I'm just adding an in-memory store. When opening up from disk, I create it using the SQLite store. Is that correct?
2. I (ostensibly) do a store migration in `writeToURL:ofType:error:` if the `url` is different. But if I set a breakpoint in `writeToURL:ofType:error:`, and then hit Save, my breakpoint is not hit. Why not?
3. If I choose "Revert to Saved", the application crashes -- hard. I have to force-quit it (and quit Xcode). Why?
4. (Very) old video tutorials suggest a way to easily bind data to a `UIView` like a table. Following along with Xcode is impossible since so much has changed. Any newer references out there for that?

Code:

`MyDocument.h`:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MyDocument : NSPersistentDocument
{
@private
    NSManagedObjectModel* mom;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator* psc;
    NSManagedObjectContext* moc;
}

@end
```

`MyDocument.m`:

```
#import "MyDocument.h"

@interface MyDocument ()
- (void)setUpManagedObjectModel;
- (void)setUpPersistentStoreCoordinator;
- (void)setUpManagedObjectContext;
- (BOOL)addPersistentStore:(NSString*)type url:(NSURL*)url error:(NSError**)outError;
@end

@implementation MyDocument

- (void)dealloc
{
    [moc release];
    [psc release];
    [mom release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setUpManagedObjectModel];
        [self setUpPersistentStoreCoordinator];
        [self setUpManagedObjectContext];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
    self = [super initWithType:typeName error:outError];
    if (self)
    {
        [self addPersistentStore:NSInMemoryStoreType url:nil error:outError];
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)readFromURL:(NSURL *)url ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
    return [self addPersistentStore:NSSQLiteStoreType url:url error:outError];
}

- (BOOL)writeToURL:(NSURL *)url ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
    NSPersistentStore* currentStore = [[psc persistentStores] lastObject];
    if (![[currentStore URL] isEqual:url])
    {
        NSPersistentStore* newStore = [psc migratePersistentStore:currentStore
                                                            toURL:url
                                                          options:nil
                                                         withType:typeName
                                                            error:outError];
        if (!newStore)
        {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return [moc save:outError];
}

- (NSString *)windowNibName
{
    // Override returning the nib file name of the document
    // If you need to use a subclass of NSWindowController or if your document supports multiple NSWindowControllers, you should remove this method and override -makeWindowControllers instead.
    return @"MyDocument";
}

- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController
{
    [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];
    // Add any code here that needs to be executed once the windowController has loaded the document's window.
}

+ (BOOL)autosavesInPlace
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)validateMenuItem:(NSMenuItem *)item
{
    NSLog(@"menu item: %@", [item title]);
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark Private Methods


- (void)setUpManagedObjectModel
{
    NSURL* modelUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyDatabase" withExtension:@"momd"];
    mom = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelUrl];
}

- (void)setUpPersistentStoreCoordinator
{
    psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
}

- (void)setUpManagedObjectContext
{
    moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];
}

- (BOOL)addPersistentStore:(NSString*)type url:(NSURL*)url error:(NSError**)outError
{
    NSDictionary* options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
    NSPersistentStore* ps = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:type
                                              configuration:nil
                                                        URL:url
                                                    options:options
                                                      error:outError];
    return (ps != nil);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `NSPersistentDocument`, by default all of this is handled for you, you don't need to do any Core Data setup. `NSPersistentDocument` will automatically handle creating, saving and migrating the persistent store.

If you want to control how the persistent store is configured, just override

```
-configurePersistentStoreCoordinatorForURL:ofType:modelConfiguration:storeOptions:error:
```

Then you can just ask the document for its `managedObjectContext` when you need it and code away.

I highly recommend you read Apple's [`NSPersistentDocument` tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSPersistentDocumentTutorial/00_Introduction/introduction.html) for more detail.

Comment: The tutorial you linked to is out of date. Especially the section "Create the User Interface", which describes steps/features that no longer exist in Xcode (4).

Comment: Also, I'm not really sure how the underlying `NSPersistentDocument` class is getting its MOM. It's definitely not from my data model, at least, not that I can tell.

Comment: Your data model must be named the same as the `NSPersistentDocument` class for everything to work automatically. i.e. if your document class is `SFDocument` then your data model should be named `SFDocument.xcdatamodel`. This is done automatically if you use the Core Data Document Application template in Xcode.

Comment: Turns out the data model doesn't need to be named anything in particular. From the documentation for the `managedObjectModel` method in `NSPeristentDocument`: "By default the framework will create a merged model of all models found in an application and its frameworks. Subclasses can return a specific model to use for creating persistent stores."